# Typo3: adding elements inside an list item <LI>

Tags: typo3

Im trying to get something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3>Some header</h3>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

inside a Text element, but when I try to apply the  blocktype to the content of the `<li>`, it applies it to the whole content.

Im using rtehtmlarea. What can I do?

Comment: Are You speaking about rich textarea field ? Which editor You are using in this case ? rtehtmlarea ?

Comment: Yes. rtehtmlarea. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange - this works in my installation. You should check the RTE configuration in page TSconfig. I assume something like this:

```
RTE.default.proc {
    allowTagsOutside = img,hr,[your Tags]
}
```

Another suggestion is: Disable the Rich Text Editor (there is a checkbox below the textarea), enter your tags, then enable it again. The tag structure should be preserved.

If not, drop me a line, I will post my RTE configuration. 
If you need a waterproof solution, try playing around with your [RTE.default typoscript](http://www.typo3-addict.com/2008/08/my-default-rte-configuration/).

Comment: i cant disable the RTE because I want to make it easy for redactors to use it, and they cant markup. what you did didnt work for me. Doesnt "allowTagsOutside" mean which tags can be outside a <p> or <div>? This is not my purpose. :(

Comment: Sure, `allowTagsOutside` was just a guess. Try this: http://pastebin.com/60jD2zLt. Maybe it works for you.

Comment: Sorry, i didnt find anything. In the end im going to use "bold" instead of "h1"